# Can you use odbc_connect() on openshift?

Tags: odbc, openshift

In openshift this code

```
<?php
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);
```

~
returns

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function odbc_connect()
```

Can you use odbc_connect() on openshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that OpenShift includes the iODBC driver, you can check for sure by creating a php page with the following contents and then checking it for iODBC support

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

You should add your request to have iODBC support at https://ideas.openshift.com and get people to vote on it.